# Changed hostname, now I can't run a tripwire check: "policy file does not match policy used to create database"

Tags: debian, hostname, integrity, tripwire

So due to problems with my hostname I just changed it. The problem with that is that in the tripwire configuration I left the hostname variable within the name of the dbfile and the local keyfile as it was. (like {$hostname}-abc.key)
First I tried simply renaming the files to match my new hostname. That didn't work.
I then used a backup and updated the tripwire configuration file as described [here](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/redhat/redhat8/rhl-rg-en-8.0/s1-tripwire-sign-config.html) without that hostname-variable to match my old hostname.
This also didn't work as I get:

> Error: Policy file does not match policy used to create database.
>   Exiting...

How can this be fixed without having to reinitialize the tripwire database? I still have an untouched (but moved and hence potentially differing ownership?) backup of my tripwire files. Maybe `chown` and alike could be used to solve this? I'm running Debian 9.1 with KDE.

<sup>And on a related note: where can I find a hash of the `siggen` file? It was missing after compilation so I had to copy it from another compilation that worked. Not sure if that warrants a separate question.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I solved this now. Here are the steps I took for that:

1. Change your hostname back to what it was before by changing it via `sudo texteditor /etc/hosts` & `sudo texteditor /etc/hostname`
2. Reboot computer and check that the name is set correctly by running `uname -n`
3. Run a check: `tripwire --check`
4. Check/save/backup the report
5. Repeat steps 1 & 2 but change the hostname to the new hostname
6. Get a backup of all the relevant tripwire files in place
7. Rebuild configuration: `sudo twadmin --create-cfgfile -S site.key twcfg.txt`
8. Regenerate local key: `sudo twadmin --generate-keys --local-keyfile {hostname}.key`
9. Recreate policy: `sudo twadmin -m P -S site.key twpol.txt`
10. Initialize the database: `sudo tripwire --init`
11. Create a new offline backup

Comment: In my case, I did not change the name of the computer. I generated a new file altogether but it was still failing the same way as you described. I found out that the initialization did not work because it would crash. I had to [comment out the /proc and /dev section](https://linux.m2osw.com/tripwire-init-not-saving-database).